# Formatting - add comma, 2 decimal places to cell values vb.net excel interop

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

Does anyone have any vb.net or vba code that will format excel values or a range of cells to have comma for 100s, 1000s,10000s etc.. and 2 decimal places only.

i.e. 10,256.45

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a reference to the range:

```
rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

The current selection is also a range, so if you want it to work with the selection, just use:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a specific custom formatting you can use **Excel styles**:

```
allRange.Style = "Comma"; // 1234.5678 -> 1,234.56
// or
allRange.Style = "Comma [0]"; // 1234.5678 -> 1,234
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **OfficeOpenXml** excel range, do like this

```
rng.Style.Numberformat.Format = "##0.00";
```